# Material design upgrade from 1 to 2

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I have an Angular 2 application which is using [Material Design](https://material.angularjs.org/) which uses `md` html tags.

Now I want to use [Material Components](https://material.angular.io/components/) which uses `mat` html tags by using the command `node_modules` upgrades.

Is there a migration guide available to do so that my existing component work as is and new component can be created using Material Components.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a guide but there is an prefix updater that automatically transforms md tags to mat

There you go: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-prefix-updater

Answer (score 0):

You could try the prefix updater as already mentioned. Note however that the original Angular Material (1.x) is for AngularJS and Material2 is for Angular, so the upgrade is exponentially more complicated than simply changing tag prefixes from 'md' to 'mat' which won't really work properly anyway. Your AngularJS code will not run under Angular by default so it will need migrating as well. Refer to the [Angular upgrading guide](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) and in particular look at `ngUpgrade`.

Comment: Currently AngularJS and Angular 2 Run application run together. We have downgraded. We are using downgradeNg2Component and loading Angular2 components into Angular1 app. These new Angular2 Components are using Material 1.x We want to utilize Material2 Now.